# Пытаюсь установить библиотеку nltk на Python 3.5, ничего не получается. что я делаю не так?

Tags: python, pip, установка, nltk

```
>>> pip install nltk
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, вы вводите эту команду в интерпретаторе питона, а надо в терминале.